# Will VBA case staements run more than one line of code?

Tags: vba

I am wondering if the VBA case statement will run more than one line of code as such:

```
Const HARD = 30

Select Case Hardness

  Case "Hard"
    If PenetrationRate.Cells(i, 1) >= Hard Then
      Total = Total + Metres.Cells(i, 1)
      DoEvents
    End If

   Case "Soft"
     If PenetrationRate.Cells(i, 1) < Hard Then
       Total = Total + Metres.Cells(i, 1)
       DoEvents
     End If

End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

When your `Select Case` statement finds a matching case, it will run all of the code until it his a new `Case` or `End Select`.. You can nest loops or any other kind of coding structure within each case.

To be overly clear, for your code when `Hardness = "Hard"` the case statement will run:

```
If PenetrationRate.Cells(i, 1) >= Hard Then
   Total = Total + Metres.Cells(i, 1)
   DoEvents
End If
```

And when `Hardness = "Soft"` the case statement will run:

```
If PenetrationRate.Cells(i, 1) < Hard Then
    Total = Total + Metres.Cells(i, 1)
    DoEvents
End If
```